# PhpStorm: AngularJS ng-repeat microSyntax not correctly evaluated by IDE

Tags: angularjs, phpstorm, webstorm

In PhpStorm 2018.3.4 there is a "Unterminated statement" warning just after the word "data" in the code below:

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in filteredData = ( tableData |
   filter: { status: filters.status||undefined,
             sequence: filters.sequence||undefined
   }
   | orderBy:orderOpt:orderReverse)"
    ng-class="data.status_class">
```

The rest of the code is OK, and the code runs smoothly in the browser.

**Is there a way to avoid this warning without disabling the "unterminated statement" inspection? Could it be a PhpStorm bug?**

The warning is shown only when there is this complex filter + orderby clauses. In simple "item in items" there is no warning.

[image: Unterminated statement warning]

Answer (score 1):

I've logged it as [WEB-37641](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-37641), please vote for this ticket to be notified on any progress with it

Answer (score 0):

After many tryouts, I concluded that it is a PhpStorm bug. Putting the entire "ng-repeat" syntax in the same line solved the issue.

It is a long line in the middle of the code but it solved my problem.